# PHP - Trying to input into MYSQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I am trying to insert into a MYSQL table database but am getting errors, and searching around has not helped a whole lot, so I am coming here to get some more hands on help.

```
<?php

$con=mysql_connect("$dbHandler","$dbLogin","$dbPass", "$dbDB") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$Rank = 1;
$Driverno = 4;
$Totalhours = 1;
$Toalpayout = 1500
$Paid = 0;

$sql="INSERT INTO AdminForm (DRIVERNO, RANK, TOTALHRS, TOTALPAYOUT, PAID)
VALUES ('$Driverno', '$Rank', '$Totalhours', '$Toalpayout', '$Paid')";


if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); // Note this doesnt actually output error for some reason
}

echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is pretty much a copy of W3school's code so I am pretty confused as to why this isnt working, as well as trying to get it to give out errors have not been working.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `mysql_connect` or `mysqli_connect`

Comment: You're mixing mysql and mysqli functions. As bad as w3schools is I doubt even they made this mistake.

Comment: You've got mysql_connect, but using mysqli everywhere else...might be it...use prepared statements with mysqli for sql injection protection. ..

Comment: As others have said, you are mixing mysql_connect and mysqli_connect (with an i). I would recommend switching to using prepared statements... PDO. Here is a decent primer on the subject: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Well I feel like a moron now, but thanks for pointing it out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different APIs.

"mysql" is a older concept, deprecated in PHP 5.5.

"mysqli" is the new concepct, used by PDO too.

You should use all call from the mysqli to make it work property.

```
//conection:
$link = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","database") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your first line,

`$con=mysql_connect("$dbHandler","$dbLogin","$dbPass", "$dbDB") or die(mysql_error());`

to

`$con = mysqli_connect("$dbHandler","$dbLogin","$dbPass","$dbDB") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));`